# Foundry : cast storage command storage slot argument posing length issue

Tags: solidity, private-blockchain, storage, foundry, cast

When I try to get the private variable stored at storage slot 0 of the contract storage  using the `cast storage` command,

```
cast storage <my-contract-address> 0 --rpc-url <my-rpc-url>
```

I get this error

```
Error: 
(code: -32602, message: Errors encountered in param 1: Storage slot argument must have a length of 66 ("0x" + 32 bytes), but '0x0' has a length of 3, data: Some(Object {"message": String("Errors encountered in param 1: Storage slot argument must have a length of 66 (\"0x\" + 32 bytes), but '0x0' has a length of 3")}))
```

I already tried to pad 0 as 0x000...0 but still get the same error.

How can this be resolved?